# Linux: no audio sound for one user logged on at same time as other (for other sound is ok)

Tags: linux, audio

(Strangely) I now have logged-on two users on Linux Mint 19.1 (`Cinnamon` desktop) and one have sound working normally (e.g. youtube in browsers), but for other user (when I switch `Ctr-Alt-F#`) laptop is silent for no apparent reason. Why could it be? What can I check to investigate?

ADDED:

For no-audio user in GUI when clicking on sound icon -> `sound settings` screen have `Dummy Output` device and no other devices, for `ok` user device is only `Speakers`. Therefore might be related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04, `pacmd list-cards` gives only `HDMI` card for no-sound user and `HDMI` + `PCH` cards for ok user and yes, as far as I remember the issue appeared on that laptop after `HMDI` usage. `aplay -l` gives both cards for both users. Maybe copying some files from home location of one user to other would fix it?

Response to comment:

```
$:cat /etc/group | grep audio
audio:x:29:pulse

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Same output for `aplay -l` (checked via `diff`).

Comment: Please check that both users are in the `audio` group by issuing the `groups` command as each of the two users. Post the output of that command by editing your question.  Kindly also add the output of `aplay -l` by both users while both are logged in.

Comment: @ Ned64, added, data seems to be same

Comment: Thanks. Please issue the `groups` command as each of the two users and post the output. Audio often only works if a user is in the `audio` group and we need to check each user individually.

Comment: @Ned64, hm..., I posted full contents of audio group already - none of users is in that group. Just be sure I did it `groups` way - ok user is only in it's same name group.

Comment: @Ned64, beg your pardon, I have not mentioned user names but thought listing `group` file contents is obvious - to clarify neither of `ordinary` users are in `audio` group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As only one user has problem,  the issue most probably related to files in that user home folder.  That link [only Dummy Output available (Mint 19)](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=284579) advises to delete files in `~/. config/pulse`.

Comment: That + restart of user session indeed solved no-sound issue for the user.